# Reply mailto link with predefined quote

Tags: html, email

I'm building a contact form and want to include a 'reply' button within the mail the receiver receives. The receiver should be able to hit this button and the original message shall be part of the new mail as a quote.

Therefore I'm trying to generate a mailto link that contains the original message as quote in the subject field. I was trying to use `<blockquote>Original message</blockquote>` and `> Original message`. It didn't work. The mail clients show it in the same way like above.

Example: `<a href="mailto:example@example.com?subject=My%20Message&amp;body=%3E%20this%20is%20the%20original%20message">Reply</a>`

What's the right syntax to put a predefined quote into a mailto link?

Comment: You need to use the "&" symbol between email variables. See these [examples](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/)

Comment: @Jamie_D It doesn't make any difference. At least Apple Mail can handle both. The `body` is at the right place, but it's showing `>` at the beginning of the message instead of showing it as the original mail text.

Comment: We just have to assume that different email clients handle mailto link variables differently.  Some may simply ignore everything but the email address completely for security reasons.